# MVC4 model property should be a list or an ICollection of another class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I'm making a type of test-generation application using Entity Framework code-first. I have a base class called `Question`, from which `MultipleChoiceQuestion`, `EssayQuestion`, and other question types descend.  `MultipleChoiceQuestions` obviously have multiple answers from which the test taker must select. My question has to do with choosing the best way to store them in the question instance.

I could declare the class with a List of Strings to hold the answers, like so:

```
public class MulitpleChoiceQuestion : Question
{
    private List<String> Answers = new List<String>();
    // other declarations, etc.
}
```

Instead I could declare another class called `Answers`, and let my `Question` classes use a collection of Answers.

```
public class Answer
{
    public int AnswerID { get; set; }
    public String AnswerText { get; set; }

    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

And then in my question subclasses (not just `MultipleChoiceQuestions`)

```
public class MulitpleChoiceQuestion : Question
{
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    // other declarations, etc.
}
```

Is there a better way than either of these? If not, which of these is better, and why? I'm having a difficult time finding anything this detailed on the web, and most books don't go this deep either. 
Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a .NET professor friend of mine this question, and this is his response:

> Both of your declarations are invoking collections. A list is a typed
>   collection while ICollection is untyped. Typed Collection (List) has
>   two advantages over untyped collections. The type of each collection
>   is checked at compile time and thus preventing runtime errors. Second,
>   they reduce the amount of casting that is needed when retrieving
>   objects.

I first implemented the ICollection solution, and it was clunky in a couple of places (for example, the Initializer for seed data):

```
    var mcQuestions = new List<MultipleChoiceQuestion>
    {
        new MultipleChoiceQuestion { 
            QuestionText = "What is the value returned by the expression (true == false? 'yes': 'no')?",
            Answers = new List<Answer> { new Answer { AnswerText="true"}, new Answer { AnswerText = "false"}, new Answer { AnswerText = "can't be determined"}, new Answer {AnswerText = "45"}, new Answer { AnswerText = "blue"}}
        },
        new MultipleChoiceQuestion { 
            QuestionText = "C-Sharp responds to a global variable declaration by:", 
            Answers = new List<Answer> { new Answer { AnswerText="throwing a compile error"}, new Answer { AnswerText = "throwing a runtime error"}, new Answer { AnswerText = "Throwing an Invalid operator warning"}, new Answer {AnswerText = "Printing a warning to the console"}, new Answer { AnswerText = "doing nothing; global variables are legal"}}
        }
    };
    mcQuestions.ForEach(mcq => context.MultipleChoiceQuestions.Add(mcq));
    context.SaveChanges();
```

Although this solution may be more flexible, I think the List will be much cleaner, and more maintainable in the long run. I can't think of a reason to keep the complexity as a trade-off for possible flexibility in the future. So it's List for me.
Hope this helps someone else out there. 
Good luck, and good code.
J

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried out something similar yet, but I would expect EF to turn your List into a seperate Answers table on your database side, so I would expect that both solutions will result in the same database model. In any case, if both methods work, deciding which one to pick is going to be a matter of taste.

Personally I would go with the List as it looks like the most simple solution and simple is generally better. If you wish your classes to better represent your database that could be a reason to make a seperate Answer class. If you expect to expand your Answer in the future, that could be another reason to pick a seperate Answer class over the simple List.

In general I would say: if you have two ways of solving a problem, the one to pick is the one that makes your code the easiest to read/understand when looking at the code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I agree, simpler is better in this case.